# is there any tool to convert html to twig?

Tags: html, symfony, twig

I am learning Symfony2, and I am making small tests.

Well I have made a small html for to test the twig templates.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test00</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">
        <img src="test.png" /><br />
        <a href="test.php">test</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the files are in the same directory of html.

Then copy all files (html, css and the images) to my test:
/var/www/Symfony/src/Test/TestBundle/Resources/views/Default
And rename the html to html.twig.

But fail when use this html as twig template, because the Symphony try to use "http://localhost/Symfony/web/test.png" as link the image.

And yes, I have read the documentation and know the "asset" and I can change the path to the files with some example
test.png')" /> and also copy all files to the web directory in the budle.

But I wonder "Is there any tool to convert html to twig?" because for example I can't say to my boss:

"The Symfony2 is great. But your designer must to learn Twig and when she finish the html with dreamweaver, she must change all of links to css and images for to make a template...and yes she can't see anything only can send to me to put in the web server to check if it is correct."

What do you hope that my boss will think about Symfony2? He will think this is crazy, this is twice of work.

I think the best it is a automatic tool to translate a html with relative paths to twig and something like that a package files to put in web dir. And the designer does'nt need to know anything only make pretty htmls with few weird things as put {{page_name}} instead the "Page name".

Regards.

Comment: +1 for the mock dialogue with your boss

Comment: Is it so wrong for a designer to learn Twig?

Answer (score 3):

From an html coders perspective, Twig is HTML. As long as templating language support is setup on your server, there is no difference between writing twig or HTML. The only difference would be the `<h1>{{variables}}<\h1>.` Your HTML coders should be aware of what variables they have access to.  That being said, from a developers perspective, twig is a lot more so I'm not simplifying twig. But if someone knows HTML, they'll know what to do with twig.

Answer (score 0):

```
Then copy all files (html, css and the images) to my test: 
/var/www/Symfony/src/Test/TestBundle/Resources/views/Default And rename the html to html.twig.
```

Nope.  Your html.twig files need to end up somewhere under views so the template processor can get to them.  However, your css and images need to be copied to your root web directory.  Same place where app.php lives.

```
But fail when use this html as twig template, because the Symphony try to use
"http://localhost/Symfony/web/test.png" as link the image.
```

It's is not symfony generating this link but your web browser.  Use Control-U to examine the generated html source from within your browser.  You will find that your links such as href="test.css" have not been changed.  Twig will not change anything unless it has has some curly brackets around it.

So your designer can continue to use her current workflow and deliver a set of files.  You just need to deploy the files to the correct locations.

Of course symfony/twig can do a lot more that simple variable replacements so eventually you might want to change things.  But you can get started just fine.